# Scrapy crawler to return only URL and Referrer when crawling

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm VERY new to scrapy, just found it yesterday and only basic python experience.

I have a group of sub-domains (around 200) that I need to map, every internal and external link.

I'm just not understanding the output side of things I think.

This is what I have so far.

```py
import scrapy

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'links'

    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow all links
        for href in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)
```

it outputs to the terminal like so:

```
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com/> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example.com/aaa/A-content-page> (referer: http://www.example.com/)
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://aaa.example.com/bbb/something/> (referer: http://www.example.com/)
```

What I'm after is a CSV or TSV

```
URL                                         Referer
http://www.example.com/                     None
http://www.example.com/aaa/A-content-page   http://www.example.com/
http://aaa.example.com/bbb/something/       http://www.example.com/
http://aaa.example.com/bbb/another/         http://aaa.example.com/bbb/something/
```

Any assistance is appreciated but would prefer a referral to docs than straight solution.

This is the solution I came up with.

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        filename = "output.tsv"
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        f.write("URL\tLink\tReferer\n")
        f.close()
        # follow all links
        for href in response.css('a::attr(href)'):            
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse)
            with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                url = response.url
                links = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
                referer = response.request.headers.get('referer', None).decode('utf-8')
                for item in links:
                    f.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n".format(url, item, referer))

        f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get both urls simply in parse.

`referer = response.request.headers.get('Referer')`
`original_url = response.url`

`yield {'referer': referer, 'url': original_url}`

You can write the output to file using

`scrapy crawl spider_name -o bettybarclay.json`

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't 100% correct this is a great start.

```
    def parse(self, response):
    filename = "output.tsv"
    # follow all links
    for href in response.css('a::attr(href)'):            
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse)
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            links = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
            referer = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
            for item in links:
                f.write("{0}\t{1}\n".format(item, referer))
```